# Accessing a variable within another python file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code in `loginPage.py`:

```
import data
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os

class login(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("700x500") #size of the window
        self.resizable(False,False) #dont let the user resize (might mess up layout of GUI)
    
    def Label(self):
        
        self.backGroundImage = PhotoImage(file = "LibraryBG.png") #photoimage for background
        self.backGroundImageLabel = Label(self, image = self.backGroundImage) #import the image as a label
        self.backGroundImageLabel.place(x=0, y=0) #placement
        
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=400,height = 330) #show a canvas in front of background
        self.canvas.place(x=150, y=70)
        
        self.titleLabel = Label(self, text = "Login", font = "Bold 30") #login text
        self.titleLabel.place(x=300, y=90)
        
        self.userNameLabel = Label(self, text = "Username", font = '8') #username text
        self.userNameLabel.place(x=200, y=180)
        
        self.passwordLabel = Label(self, text = "Password", font = '8') #password text
        self.passwordLabel.place(x=200, y=220)

    def Entry(self):  
        # these are the 2 entryboxes for the password and username
        self.userNameEntry = Entry(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.userNameEntry.place(x=320, y=185, width=175, height=20)
        
        self.passwordEntry = Entry(self, borderwidth=0, show ='*', highlightthickness=0)
        self.passwordEntry.place(x=320, y=225 , width=175, height=20)
    
    def Button(self):
        #this button calls the login function once pressed
        self.loginButtonImage = PhotoImage(file = "LoginButton.png")
        self.loginButton = Button(self, image = self.loginButtonImage, command = self.Login, border = 0)
        self.loginButton.place(x=290,y=280)
        
    def Login(self):
        if self.userNameEntry.get() in data.employees.index:
            if int(self.passwordEntry.get()) == data.employees.loc[self.userNameEntry.get(),'password']:
                self.withdraw()
                os.system('main.py')
            else: 
                self.titleLabel = Label(self, text = "Your username and/or password doesn't exist.\n Please try again or contact the admin.", fg = '#FF0000', font = "8")
                self.titleLabel.place(x=200, y=100)
        else:
            self.titleLabel = Label(self, text = "Your username and/or password doesn't exist.\n Please try again or contact the admin.", fg = '#FF0000', font = "8")
            self.titleLabel.place(x=200, y=100) 
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    Login = login()
    Login.Label()
    Login.Entry()
    Login.Button()
    Login.mainloop()
```

In my other file `main.py`, how can I use the `Entry` that is created by the line `self.userNameEntry = Entry(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)`?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is import the variable. But to do this, you first need the `Login` variable to be global. You also need to run the methods needed initalize `Login`. To do this, just change the end of `loginPage.py` to this:

```
Login = login()
Login.Label()
Login.Entry()
Login.Button()

if __name__=="__main__":
    Login.mainloop()
```

Note that `Login.mainloop()` is only run if you directly run `python loginPage.py`.

Then, from `main.py`, you can import `Login` and access it's `userNameEntry` property. Like this:

```
from loginPage import Login

print(Login.userNameEntry)
```